# iOS 8 automaticatically add space after emoji icon for colored string in UITextView

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uitextview, nsattributedstring, emoji

I am using apple TextKit **IntroToTextKitDemo2013** sample code in my app.

Here is the sample code [link](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=WWDC%202013#)

It dynamically changes color of **UITextView AttributedString** if it is 'Alice' or 'Rabbit'

When I enter "#" symbol it works fine as shown but when I enter "#" after emoji icon it adds space after emoji and "#" symbol.
I am using iOS 8.3

**Here is my code**

```
    //ControllerCode

@property (nonatomic, retain) TKDInteractiveTextColoringTextStorage *textStorage;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // our auto layout views use a design spec that calls for
    // 8 pts on each side except the bottom
    // since we scroll at the top here, only inset the sides

    CGRect newTextViewRect = CGRectInset(self.view.bounds, 8., 0.);

    self.textStorage = [[TKDInteractiveTextColoringTextStorage alloc] init];

    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];

    NSTextContainer *container = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(newTextViewRect.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    container.widthTracksTextView = YES;
    [layoutManager addTextContainer:container];
    [_textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];

    UITextView *newTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:newTextViewRect textContainer:container];
    newTextView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    newTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    newTextView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;

    [self.view addSubview:newTextView];
    self.textView = newTextView;

    self.textStorage.tokens = @{ @"Alice" : @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor] },
                                 @"Rabbit" : @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor orangeColor] },
                                 TKDDefaultTokenName : @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor] } };
}

-(void)setDemo:(TKDDemo *)demo
{

    [super setDemo:demo];
    (void)[self view];

    [_textStorage beginEditing];
    [_textStorage setAttributedString:self.demo.attributedText];
    [_textStorage endEditing];
}
```

[image: Space added after #]

[image: # without space]

Comment: @Waseem05 did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue, added Font to attribute string and works fine for me

```
[attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                         value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Regular" size:16.0]
                         range:NSMakeRange(0, [self.capTextView.text length])];
```

Answer (score 1):

TextKit doesn't handle it very well. Different line heights are derived from different fonts' metrics. English text has "SFUIText" on iOS 10, and "AppleColorEmojiUI" for emoji.

One possible way it swizzle `lineHeight` and other methods of UIFont, returning the value of system default font. Or control the line rects manually by implement the NSLayoutMangerDelegate.

[Neat](https://github.com/leavez/Neat) is recommended to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks really for your help but this issue appeared to me when I was converting my iOS 7 project to iOS 8 at that time initially apple has this bug of adding  automatically 3 spaces after emoji for coloured string which reduce to 1 space after 2 (versions iOS 8.3 arrived) I posted this question on stackoverflow but I not worked on this project for new versions like iOS 10